# JPA Criteria query to fetch data from master and child table with entitygraph

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to fetch data from parent to child both based on filter criteria using JPA Criteria query so that can avoid multiple queries to DB, but not able to achieve desired result. Following are my sample entities( without getters/setters)

```
@Entity
public class ParentTable implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "KEY_COLUMN",length = 30)
    private String keyColumn;

    @Column(name = "CODE",length = 30)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "KEY_DESC",length = 240)
    private String desc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentTable",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ChildTable> childTableList;
}


@Entity
public class ChildTable implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ChildTable() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID",length = 80)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_KEY_COLUMN",length = 30,insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private String parentKeyColumn;

    @Column(name = "CHILD_CODE",length = 30)
    private String childCode;

    @Column(name = "CHILD_DESC",length = 240)
    private String chldDesc;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_KEY_COLUMN", referencedColumnName = "KEY_COLUMN")
    private ParentTable parentTable;

}
```

Criteria builder snippet -

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ParentTable> query = cb.createQuery(ParentTable.class);
Root<ParentTable> fromParent = query.from(ParentTable.class);
Join<ParentTable, ChildTable> details = fromParent.join("childTableList");

List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList();
conditions.add(cb.equal(details.get("childCode"), childCode));
conditions.add(cb.equal(details.get("chldDesc"),chldDesc));

TypedQuery<ParentTable> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query.select(fromParent).where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
List<ParentTable> parentTableList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

This executes and gives result of parent table only, if i fetch childtable data I can see JPA query getting exceuted again, can this be avoided and fetch list of child entities which matches 3 dynamic params? 1. ParentTable.code, 2. ChildTable.childCode , 3. ChildTable.chldDesc .

Can anyone help me to construct JPA query like below which executes in one DB hit instead of multiple round trip, which is happening in above snippet of code?

```
select * from ParentTable p,ChildTable c where p.KEY_COLUMN=c.PARENT_KEY_COLUMN and p.CODE=? and c.CHILD_CODE=? and c.CHILD_DESC=?
```

**Update :**

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ParentTable> cq = builder.createQuery(ParentTable.class);
Root<ParentTable> root = cq.from(ParentTable.class);
Join<ParentTable, ChildTable> join = root.join("childTableList");

Predicate p1=builder.equal(root.get("code"), "code");
Predicate p2=builder.like(join.get("chldDesc"), "%chldDesc%");
Predicate p3=builder.equal(join.get("childCode"), "childCode");
Predicate andPredicate = builder.and(p1,p2, p3);
cq.select(root).where(andPredicate);

EntityGraph<ParentTable> fetchGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(ParentTable.class);
fetchGraph.addSubgraph("childTableList");
List<ParentTable> parentTableList=entityManager.createQuery(cq).setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", fetchGraph).getResultList();
parentTableList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This approach forms the expected query like above mentioned but again one more query is formed like below , why second query is triggered even-though its not required?

```
select * from ParentTable  parentTable0_ where parentTable0_.code=?
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA is required to give you managed entity results that reflect the data in the database. The filter you put on the query does not filter the internal relationships.

Your 'join' clause only affects the filter applied to returning ParentTable entities. Every entity returned will have a complete 'childTableList' collection, so even though you are returning ParentTable instances that have specific codes and descriptions, the childTableList shows all its children. That is JPA for you, and specific providers do have a way to filter these mapped collections ([AdditionalCriteria](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_additionalcriteria.htm) ) IMO they are a bad route with many problems.

If you want to have childTableEntries that match the specific codes and descriptions, your query should be more of the form (using JPQL)

```
"Select c, p from ChildTable c join c.parentTable p where c.childCode = :code and c.chldDesc = :desc"
```

This will return you a List result, where the Object array has the child and parent entries for each row that matches. So duplicate parents if one has more than one child that matches.

Otherwise, the extra query is being caused by accessing the childTableList on the parentTable entries, because they are marked lazy. Your criteria query is specifying 'join', as you want to use the childTableList entries in filtering parentTable entities. If you want the childTableList fetched with the parentTables, you need to use fetchJoins. Root implements [FetchParent](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch(javax.persistence.metamodel.PluralAttribute)), which would allow you to specify a 'fetch' on the childTableList in addition to the join you've defined. In JPQL, something like:

```
 "select p from ParentTable p fetch join p.childTableList, join p.childTableList c where c.childCode = :code and c.chldDesc = :desc"
```